# Which 15" MacBook Pro should I buy? 2015 or 2016?

Tags: macbook-pro

I need a new laptop and I am wondering if I should buy the 15" MacBook Pro 2015 or the new MacBook Pro 2016.

Which one you recommend?
Is it really worthy the 2016 upgrade?

I hope my question is not off topic.
Thanks

Comment: Currently, the question is almost entirely based on opinion. It would help if you could list what you are going to use the MBP for, and whether there are any constraints on price, or whether there are certain features/disadvantages that you don't require/bother you. If not, you could just review the tech specs of both MBPs and compare yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have listed some of the differences here, but if you want a full comparison, see [here](http://www.apple.com/mac/compare/results/?product1=macbook-pro-2015-15&product2=macbook-pro-touchbar-15).

- Thinner
- Touch Bar
- Touch ID
- Wide Color Gamut
- Brighter display
- Better Battery life
- Only 4 Thunder Bolt 3 ports which double as USB C and charging(you will have to use adapters for more)
- Bluetooth 4.2
- No MagSafe
- Better processors
- Bigger trackpad
- More storage

Comment: thanks..the thing is that I am aware about all the specs and actually I desire more a suggestion/opinion about which one purchase..at the moment I am running on a Late 2011 Macbook pro 15" and to be more than honest..he never disappointed me. but the new one it is so expensive and maybe doesn't worth me to buy it when I can get the 2015 model for less..

Comment: yes! thanks indeed! my comment was for the other possible respondents

Comment: How is the battery "better"? The capacity shrunk and batt life/efficiency is also not great. TBar means less FKeys on an overall *very*error prone keyboard. On the plus side you may add weight and improved fans (but not so sure for cooling)?

Comment: @LangLangC I was just listing what was on the website. Apple's tech specs says the 2016 one lasts an hour longer in web browsing.

Comment: Yeah, in artificial testing. But instead of just copying the marketing department's hyperbole [this](https://www.cnet.com/news/macbook-pro-october-2016-battery-life/) or [that](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-touch-bar-faq/macbook-pro-touch-bar-late-2016-battery-life.html) might be considered. You wrote: '16 model was "a disappointment". We gained some and we lost some. –– "Better battery" is so ambivalent here since another round of 99.5Wh would have given that much more productivity in real life compared to synthetic benchmarks. Some real-world tests were not good.